# Previous and Next tags with conditional to display pipe character

Tags: conditionals, template-scripting

This is my template code

```
{exp:channel:prev_entry channel="events"}
    <a href="{path='events/article'}" title="Previous Offer | {title}">PREVIOUS EVENT</a>
{/exp:channel:prev_entry}

{if '{next}' !='' AND '{prev}' !=''}|{/if}

{exp:channel:next_entry channel="events"}
  <a href="{path='events/article'}" title="Next Offer | {title}">NEXT EVENT</a>
{/exp:channel:next_entry}
```

Notice the conditional in the middle **{if '{next}' !='' AND '{prev}' !=''}|{/if}** I've tried every which way to get this pipe character to only display if there are both a next and a previous entry but not if there is only one of them. I've tried AND XOR OR and also checking for != or == but nothing seems to work. I either get the pipe for all results or it never displays.

What is the correct way to get the pipe character to display only if there are both a next and a previous entry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not seeing a "{prev}" or "{next}" variable listing in the EE 2.5.3 docs for channel entries (I'm assuming you're doing this on a single-entry template).

Have you tried using the {paginate}{/paginate} tag pair? (http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/pagination_page.html)

I'm wondering if something like this will work:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="some-channel" sort="desc" limit="1" paginate="bottom"}
{paginate}
    {if previous_page}
        <a href="{auto_path}">Previous Page</a> &nbsp;
    {/if}
    {if previous_page and next_page}|{/if}
    {if next_page}
        <a href="{auto_path}">Next Page</a>
    {/if}
{/paginate}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Patrick, I'm going to take a look at that. This is an older site that I inherited. Must look closer at the code. Running 2.2.2

Comment: Taking this approach, be sure to `disable="member_data|categories|custom_fields"` to cut down on overhead.

Comment: Also note that the pagination tag pair got a LOT more powerful as of 2.3.0, so you might have to upgrade to make this work.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a solution that uses entry linking (rather than pagination as Patrick suggested) then either of these add-ons will allow you to do conditionals based on whether there are next/prev entries or not.

[Entry Linking](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/entry-linking)

[Advanced Prev Next Entry](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/advanced-prev-next-entry)